# PHP Sessions and Classes

Tags: php, class, session

I feel like a big noob. Okay in PHP I am a noob but that's another story.
I am a bid confused. I wrote a ticket system for a smaller company and it works well.
There is just 1 problem with my session variables.

```
define('bin', 'bin/');//just the path to my binaries
session_name('ticket');

require_once bin.'constants.php'; //definition of all necessary constants
require_once bin.'class.php';   //Load all class files
$boolsession = session_start();
require_once bin.'handle.php'; //execute all incomming data
require_once bin.'webcontent.php'; //output the result.
```

And here is my Problem. When I start the Session BEFORE I include my class files there are some variables which just don't work anymore. When is start it after like this there is just 1 variable which doesn't get started anymore.

It's my user variable which refers to my user data.
After I logged in it write my session I insert the data out of my name user in a variable and write it into my session.

```
$_SESSION['user'] = $user;
```

But when I process more data my 'user' won't work anymore. Var dump shows me that user is incomplete

somehow like this

> object(__PHP_Incomplete_Class)#1 (5) { ["__PHP_Incomplete_Class_Name"]=> string(4) "user"

Answer (score 0):

You indeed *must* include your class files before you start the session. Unserialising objects from session needs the source-files of the classes.

Comment: do you have session.auto_start = true in your php.ini?